# Stroke-line cap on iPad Retina

Tags: css, svg, retina-display

I have a simple SVG image which is rendered differently on iPad Retina and MacBook Pro with Retina display (both Chrome and Safari). As soon as you add `stroke-linecap` to your `rect` element, the `stroke-width` is rendered double the normal width.

Here is the example where two rectangles should have the same border width (check it on iPad): [SVG rectangle with/without linecap](http://jsfiddle.net/bakhshi/uS2P2/).

Is there a unit specifier for `stroke-width` which I am missing or there is other solutions?

Comment: well, one solution could be using media query `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2` and reducing the stroke width of rectangle with line-cap to half the normal width which is not really accurate when pixel-ratio is not 2.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer an issue in iOS 9, based on experiments with the iOS Simulator.

[image]

Comment: cool! didn't have the chance to test it on ios 9. but that looks good.